# VOIP App window (in foreground) blocked from receiving user input during Active Cellular Call

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, voip, banner, background-foreground

During an active VOIP call, my app is put into the background when an incoming cellular call is received and answered. If, while on the cellular call, I bring my app back to the foreground the app view appears but is unresponsive. The "Touch to return to call" banner appears at the top of the view in green but the app view appears as if there is a darker transparent window overlaid on top of it preventing the view from receiving input. If I put my app into the background, bring another app to the foreground and then bring my app back to the foreground everything works as expected so the problem seems to be specific to active cell calls and/or the green banner only? In Settings->Notifications->Phone I tried turning Notification Center OFF and Alert Style NONE in the hopes of removing the banner to see if the problem still exists but these settings do not effect that banner. In addtion to the App window appearing to have a transparent window overlaid on it, if I touch the window I'm able to drag the entire app window (or view) in all directions (up down side to side) and it has a bounce effect (like tableview vertical scroll) when I release it.

If I dont know the problem I cannot fix it (:

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's no view being added on top your view which might be intercepting all your events? My second guess would've been that your app received a memory warning and unloaded a bunch of views. However, that's not very likely since you still see all the views.

Comment: I believe that the issue is related to the banner displayed by iOS at the top "Touch to return to call". Its display seems to prevent my application view from receiving input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really mean to "bring your app back to the foreground",but I can tell you for sure that you cannot call in the same thread the UI and the incoming call, so for situations like this when you want to render some view during a call you can try something like this:

```
public void InvokeGUIThread(Action action)
{
  Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}
```

For example if you want to set a text in a textblock do something like this:

```
InvokeGUIThread(() =>
        {
            textBlockSome.Text = e.Item.ToString();
        });
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, while my app is in use, I receive an incoming cell call so the native phone client comes to the foreground. I answer the call and then double tap home button to display running apps and I choose mine which makes it the active app (the native phone client is put to the background), but my app appears to have this transprent window overlaid and my app does not receive gesture events. Only while native phone client has active call, problem doe not exist if I repeat the steps above with another application.... Thanks...